# Why is time complexity of k-way merge sort O(nk^2)?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I'm comparatively new to algorithm analysis and am taking a related course on coursera where I came accross k way merge sort.

The time complexity of 2 way merge sort is `n log2 n`, of 3 way merge sort is `n log3 n` and of 4 way merge sort is `n log4 n`.

But, in the case of k-way the complexity is nk^2. This is because we pay attention to the merge part of the algo; `(2n + 3n + 4n...kn)`.

But, in case of 2, 3 and 4-way algorithms, we pay attention to the recursive call of one function; `(2T(n/2) + c.n)`.

Can anybody please explain why this is so? Or correct my approach to this question.

Answer (score 1):

the recursion depth is `log n/log k`,

merging costs `n*log k`, using a min heap for `log k` per element

thus we come at `T(n) = n* log k + K* T(n/k)` which (unless I'm mistaken) becomes `n log n` ([actually `n (c_1/k+log(n))= n/k + n*log(n)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+n%2a+log+k+%2B+kT%28n%2Fk%29) but the `n/k` becomes insignificant in big O)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the complexity of k way merge sort is O(knlog_k(n)) not O(nk^2) without implementing other algorithms or data structures. O(kn) per step of the algorithm, and log_k(n) steps. Doubt you still need an answer tho since it has been seven years...